# Programmatically sending e-mail doesn't go through Template.php?

Tags: email, magento

I recently asked a question as to how to send e-mails programmatically in Magento and I got some great replies. The post is here: [Is it possible to send an e-mail programmatically in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582691).

There were a couple of methods suggested. I implemented the one here: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-custom-emails/

and I made the changes to Template.php suggested in this post:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/1073/P30/

because I could find nowhere to enter credentials for my email server (I really can't believe I have to change that file. Why can't I enter those details in the system admin in the same place as the smtp host?).

I still didn't get my e-mail. So I put a Mage::log call in getMail() and the message did not appear in my system.log. Is the method of sending the e-mail, taken from inchoo.net, wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Inchoo's way is the best method for sending mails through Magento's stack, you can try and just use a simple Zend_Mail object to be sure it's not a misconfiguration within Magento itself.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html

If a basic Zend_Mail send() doesn't do the trick, then I would suggest checking your servers internal mail server settings for testing there to ensure its functioning properly.

On a side note, be sure and check spam folders, I know its obvious but can be over looked sometimes.