# bulk invite in Magento

Tags: php, magento

How would I go about creating a bulk invite feature in Magento?

The steps would be:

1. An admin fills in a form with a comma separated list of emails.
2. Email recipient gets an email containing a link to the client registration page of Magento. In Magento this would be the page "/customer/account/create/".

Is there a free module that lets me do this?  If not, how can I get started in adding a page in the admin screen which would allow me to send emails?

Thanks.

Comment: why do you need a module for this? it would be a lot easier to use a bulk email app like mailchimp for this purpose.

Comment: @sulabh My client wants this functionality in their admin dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating my own module which sends email during a form post. I got my ideas here:

[Send email via Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582691/is-it-possible-to-send-an-e-mail-programmatically-in-magento)